# Core Bluetooth - modifying a service with new characteristics or fewer characteristics

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have an app using `Core Bluetooth` where I want the peripheral manager to add or remove characteristics from a service. I can add new characteristics the same way I set them up in the first place:

`serialService.characteristics.append(newCharacteristic)`

but what if I want to remove an existing characteristic? I can get an array of the existing characteristics. I initialize like so: `let newCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cbuuid, properties: [.read,.notify], value: nil, permisions: .readable)`. It seems like I should be able to loop through the characteristics array and query `type` for the one I want to remove, but I don't see `type` as a property I can query. Is that accessible somewhere? Or do I need to build the service from scratch instead of modifying it?

After amending the service, how do I notify the central of the change? Do I remove the service and then add it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why the first parameter of `CBMutableCharacteristic` is initialized with a parameter called "type." This is a bit confusing (even in ObjC). The name of the property you want is `uuid`.

[Changing a CBMutableService once you've added it doesn't make any changes to it.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmutableservice#) You'll need to remove the service and re-add it.

> After you add a service to the peripheral’s local database, Core Bluetooth caches the service and you can no longer make changes to it.

Once you remove and re-add the service, that will modify the GATT database and trigger a notification to the central. The Bluetooth-standard way to handle this is using the Service Changed characteristic (0x2a05), but it's possible Apple does this in a proprietary way if you're talking between Apple devices. If these are both iOS devices, you should expect the central's CBPeripheralDelegate to receive `peripheral(_:didModifyServices:)` (possibly twice, once for removing, and once for adding).

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I expected (except the `uuid` part. Thanks for that). I had confirmed the behavior you predicted when I rebuilt the service from scratch, which should be equivalent to removing an item.

Comment: @Rob Napier does it trigger didModifyServices call back if one of two device is not ios ?